# Can I associate a single custom domain name with multiple organizations (same account) #bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a single bluemix account for our company, serving multiple BUs, which each have their own organization in bluemix.

Each organization provides sites and services and we want all applications to be available on the same common domain name.

Can I re-use the same custom domain name in multiple organizations in bluemix? For each application I will assign a unique subdomain of course.

Or is this bad practice? Should I rather create a single organization and multiple spaces, one for each BU, instead? (Which would of course eliminate the problem - perhaps I have the answer!).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to do `cf share-private-domain OTHER_ORG MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`.  This is a general feature of open-source Cloud Foundry, so it should work on Bluemix as well, but you should try it out to be certain.